# Is my loop set up correctly in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop

I need to code to return two different error messages for different outputs. 
one for then the users input is blank and another for if the users input is not y or n.  I am running in to the problem of my code returning only the error message for the not y or n because I have that message to return if the user inputs anything other than y or n. The code will return the right error message for the blank error once but then after that is gets stuck on just returning the error message for the not y or n. any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
while (choice.isEmpty()) 
{
    System.out.println("Error! This entery is required. Try again."); 
    choice = sc.nextLine(); 
} 

while (!(choice.equalsIgnoreCase ("y") || choice.equalsIgnoreCase ("n")))
{
    System.out.println ("Error! Please enter y, Y, n, or N. Try again ");
    choice = sc.nextLine(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably better off with one loop:

```
while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
    if (choice.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Error! This entry is required. Try again.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error! Please enter y, Y, n, or N. Try again.");
    }

    choice = sc.nextLine(); 
}
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen True, but since the original call was not in the snippet provided by OP, I didn't take it into account. If I were to write this myself, I'd be closer to your version. I didn't add that to my answer since I didn't want to overlap with yours.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need a single loop here:

```
String choice = "";
do {
    choice = sc.nextLine();
    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println ("Error! Please enter y, Y, n, or N. Try again ");
    }
} while (true);
```

Note that this approach correctly handles all inputs, including the first one when the input has not yet been previously defined.

Comment: @ScaryWombat `NOT(p OR q)` is logically equivalent to `NOT p AND NOT q`, which is the version used in Robby's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't describe what you want to achieve, if it's an *infinite loop* (as long as `sc.nextLine()` returns something) where the users can enter only 'y' or 'n':

```
while((choice = sc.nextLine()) != null) {
    if(choice.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Error! This entry is required. Try again.");
    } else if(!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        System.out.println("Error! Please enter y, Y, n, or N. Try again.");
    } else {
        // do whatever you need
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(choice = sc.nextLine()) {` does not equate to a boolean

Comment: `// do whatever you need` plus `break;` ?

Comment: Ooops, forgot the check against `null`. The OP didn't disclose the nature of the `sc` variable so I took that `sc.nextLine()` is referring to a scanner, which will return `null` if there are no more lines, hence breaking the loop. As for adding a `break`, based on his attempt I assumed he wants an infinite loop.